# camera application gets stuck after taking pic and do not return to my application

Tags: android, camera, freeze

I am using nexus 5 for testing.
Sometimes my Camera application gets stuck/hang after taking pic and do not return to my application. It return after few second and on activityResult() does not get called. and  in samsung galaxy j5 sometimes white screen appears after clicking pic.

My code

```
public void openCamera() {



        if (!checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, context)) {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, 11, getActivity());
            return;
        }

        if (!checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, context)) {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 121, getActivity());
            return;
        }

        if (!checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, context)) {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 121, getActivity());
            return;
        }
        boolean flag = true;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            flag = false;
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            UtilityMethods.saveException(ex.getMessage(),"ab");
        }


        if (photoFile != null&&flag) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }else {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            }

            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);




        }else{
            UtilityMethods.saveException("file exception"+photoFile,"abc");
        }
    }
```

Another method

```
 private File createImageFile() throws Exception {


        String imageFileName = "JPEG_img";


        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
            if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );


        pathOfPic = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: will you please tell me what is configuration of your device by which you are testing...

Comment: the problem is in nexus 5 and samsung j 5. I think it is not about configuation.

Comment: yes you may be right raman but to solve the issue each and every aspect is important as we dont know the exact cause for the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with files has been chnaged in API 24.
Here is the solution for you:

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

Comment: yeah i have used Fileprovider for api 24 . but this problem is on lower versions

Comment: Please describe the problem with more details and provide full source. Where do you call startActivityForResult for an instance ?

Comment: sorry that was missed by me

Comment: After this line , i called the intent ,in openCamera() method

               " intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);            
                startActivityForResult(intent, 12);